# How can I run a Javascript code after 5min of loading the web?

Tags: wordpress

I have a piece of code in Javascript, I would like to be able to run it after 5min that my web has fully loaded. It's possible? How could I do it?

This is the code that I want you to run, after 5 minutes.

```
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5c34cd02361b3372892f0a3e/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job for you.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // code here
  }, 300000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to do exactly that.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // put your code here
    }, 5*60*1000);
});
```